# How can I add more buttons for other actions without messing up my virtual joystick?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch, drag

I've been trying to get this done for a few hours now without any luck. I'm pretty new to Unity3D and C# so that could be the reason why I can't seem to make it work.

I have a canvas, and a round button added to it that acts like a joystick. On the button, in the inspector menu, I have 2 Event Triggers, one for Drag and one for End Drag. Each calls its own separate function "StartDrag();" and "EndDrag();" which work just fine, making the joystick work properly.

The issue I'm having, is that if I add a new button, say for a "jumping" action, if I press it while I'm using the joystick, the button from the joystick doesn't keep its position, it gets affected by the new touch messing up the movement. Bellow you can see the code that does work for the joystick. How can I add more buttons for other actions without messing up my joystick? Thank you very much in advance and if possible, please keep in mind that my C# and Unity experience is very limited.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class JoystickMovement : MonoBehaviour {

private Vector3 joystick_center;
public GameObject Player;
public PlayerData playerDataScript;

void Start () {
    joystick_center = transform.position;
}

public void StartDrag(){
    float x = Input.mousePosition.x;
    float y = Input.mousePosition.y;

    Vector3 joyPosition = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(new Vector3 (x-joystick_center.x, y-joystick_center.y, 0), 80) + joystick_center;
    transform.position = joyPosition;
}

public void ResetDrag(){
    transform.position = joystick_center;
    Player.rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
}

void FixedUpdate () {

    if(playerDataScript.playerStatus == "dead")
    {
        ResetDrag();
    }

    if (playerDataScript.playerStatus == "alive") 
    {
        Player.rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(Player.rigidbody.velocity, 4);
        Player.rigidbody.AddRelativeForce (new Vector3(transform.position.x - joystick_center.x, 0, transform.position.y - joystick_center.y));

    }
}
```

}

Comment: it would be such a nice weekend if anyone could help : / .. still haven't found a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with my code is that I need to identify which touch I need to watch for my joystick. When I have 2 fingers on the screen, the joystick kind of gets confused. In order to see which touch I need, I can just try and use ONLY the touch that's around my joystick by comparing its x or y coordinate, to my joystick's original coordinate. If they're close, then I can have it run that particular code using just that specific touch.

```
void Update() 
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < Input.touchCount)
    {
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).position.x > joystick_center.x - 150 && Input.GetTouch(i).position.x < joystick_center.x + 150)
        {
            if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase != TouchPhase.Ended && Input.GetTouch(i).phase != TouchPhase.Canceled && playerDataScript.playerStatus == "alive")
            {

                //joystick movement code

            } else {
                // reset joystick movement
            }
        }

        ++i;
    }
}
```